# What life could survive in a backrooms-like enviroment

Tags: biology, fauna, flora, microorganisms

[image: The Backrooms]

you know what the backrooms are, you're on the internet.

for those who somehow don't: the backrooms is an internet urban legend that entails a pocket dimension that you can get to via no-clipping through reality, it's all corridors, the walls are moldy, ugly, and yellow, the carpet is moist and also moldy, the only source of light is loudly buzzing fluorescent lights in the ceiling.

So, what living things could arise in this sort of environment?

We already have the mold, but what about things more complex than mold? could a whole ecosystem arise filled with plants growing along the floor and walls and creatures eating the plants?

Comment: Well - you already have living mold, so at the very lest you have that and probably whatever can eat it.

Comment: I see an electrical cirquit, so Mynocks might survive there.

Comment: @brhans yeah fair, but could more complex life than just molds and assorted insects live in an environment like this? Could photosynthetic organisms develop to capture the rays of fluorescent lights? even the molds gotta eat

Comment: imo this is entirely up to your imagination, since the backrooms are, themselves, imaginary. Where does the water come from? What are the corridors made from (presumably drywall)? Why doesn't it dry out? Who replaces broken lights? Where does the electricity come from? The backrooms needs better definition to have an ecosystem. If the definition is "it's fantasy, the details are never explained" then the flora and fauna can work the same way. There's monsters. What do they eat? Same thing that feeds the light bulbs: fantasy.

Comment: @JamieB but thats not really true is it? If someone says “my magic flame spell can juuuust melt aluminum, how hot is the spell?”. The fantasy element is fluff, not important to the actual answer at all. At worst you could say “what type of aluminum” but a proper answer would skip that and immediately go to “this is the lowest and this the highest melting point for aluminum types”. In this case the rooms have an infinite supply of run down water, paint, drywall, concrete floors and whatever wallpaper as well as mold. What can live on those materials if it accidentally clipped there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said twice it's moldy. That means a kind of life called mold lives there.

There are 36 species of indoor mold listed in Table 1 of Vesper, S., McKinstry, C., Haugland, R., Wymer, L., Bradham, K., Ashley, P., … Friedman, W. (2007). Development of an Environmental Relative Moldiness Index for US Homes. Journal of Occupational and Environmental Medicine, 49(8), 829–833. doi:10.1097/jom.0b013e3181255e98

They are mostly from the aspergillus and penicillium genera.

Probably cockroaches too.